# Solr 6: Error loading class 'solr.CollationKeyFilterFactory'

Tags: solr, lucene, ezplatform

I'm working on a project based on ez Platform CMS connected with SOLR (version 6.6.6). (more detals: https://doc.ezplatform.com/en/2.5/guide/search/solr/)

Now I'm trying configure Solr to deal with sorting with special characters (especially polish).

I have found that I need to add filter `solr.CollationKeyFilterFactory` to my managed-schema like this:

```
<!-- sorl/server/ez/myappcore/conf/managed-schema -->

<fieldType name="string" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CollationKeyFilterFactory" language="pl" country="PL" strength="primary" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And next load required jars by add `<lib>` to `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<!-- sorl/server/ez/myappcore/conf/solrconfig.xml -->

<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>6.6.6</luceneMatchVersion>

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />

  <!-- added libs below -->
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-analysis-extras-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/analysis-extras/lib/" regex="morfologik-\w*-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs/" regex="lucene-analyzers-morfologik-\d.*\.jar" />

  <!-- rest of config ... -->
</config>
```

but after restarting Solr (`bin/solr stop -p 8983 && bin/solr -s ez`) in dashboard (`http://localhost:8983/solr/`) I have error message:

> myappcore: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core myappcore: Can't load schema /Users/maciek/Sites/solr/solr-6.6.6/server/ez/myappcore/conf/managed-schema: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "string": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error loading class 'solr.CollationKeyFilterFactory'

I think there is a problem with missing or not loaded one of the jars (`Error loading class 'solr.CollationKeyFilterFactory'`) but I have no idea where I'm wrong...

so please help because I have spent hours to search any info on Internet and random tries...

Many thanks! ;)

Comment: It did not failed for me. The reason is the name of the fieldType used. You have used the fieldType name as string. There already exist  fieldType string. Try by giving some different name to your fieldType

Comment: Also be aware that [the CollationField has replaced](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_5_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/CollationField.html) most of what the CollationKeyFilter was used for, as far as I know.